# How do I automatically reconnect my AirPods when my Mac wakes from sleep?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, bluetooth, airpods

When my Mac sleeps, my AirPods disconnect (as expected, I suppose); but when I wake my Mac, I must go through the full process of connecting them again from scratch (either through the Bluetooth menu or by placing them back in the case and removing them again).

Is there a way to have my AirPods automatically reconnect to my Mac after it wakes from sleep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Bluetooth:

[image: Bluetooth Preferences]

Open AirPods Options and select "Connect to This Mac Automatically":

[image: AirPods Options]